# Finding all constant solutions for the differential equation y'=sin(y)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For my homework of finding ALL the constant solutions of given differential equations, a trigonometric function popped up
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = sin(y)$$
Unfortunately i'm new to differential equations and I could only prove it true for y=0
but when I plotted it on Desmos I could see that it was true for every multiple of pi. I was wondering how I could prove that, and how to deal with finding constant solutions for differential equations with trigonometric fucntions in general.

Comment: This can be solved by the separation of variables: $\frac{\text{d}y}{\sin y} = \text{d}x$. Integrating both sides leads to the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y = C$ is a solution, then $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}(C) = 0$.  Substituting both into the differential equation:

$$0 = \sin(C)$$

Solving this for $C$ gives $C = \pi k$ for some integer $k$.